# Discord.js not sending random responces

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a discord js bot. For some reason when my bot uses random responses like this, the application does not and does respond randomly.

I even tried having an array for responses but discord js gave me a hassle about that as well.

On top of this, for whatever reason, when I tried removing the catches next to the replies (the promise version) it would not work, and when it does the catch always fires.

8ball file:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { logging } = require('../index')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('8ball')
        .setDescription('Ask me a question')
        .addStringOption(opt => opt.setName('question').setDescription('question you have for meh').setRequired(true)),
    
    async execute(interaction) {
        logging.info(`Log:8ball command was called printing a random message`);
        let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        if(interaction.options.getString('question').includes('?') === true) {
            await interaction.reply({ content:'Sorry, but this command does not support question marks', ephemeral:true })
                .catch(logging.error(`Log:A error occurred while trying to send error message in 8ball`))
        
            return;
        }
        if (randomnumber === 1) {
            log.info(`Log:A response 0 was selected, printing response 0`);
            try {
                await interaction.reply('Q: ' + interaction.options.getString('question') + '\nA: yes, i suppose');

            }
            catch {
                await interaction.followUp('An error occurred while attempting to send the reply, please try again')
                    .catch(logging.error(`Log:A error occurred while trying to send error message `))
                    .then(logging.error( 'A error occurred while sending response 1, returning'))
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (randomnumber === 2) {
            log.info(`Log:A response 2 was selected, printing response 2`);

            try {
                await interaction.reply('Q: ' + interaction.options.getString('question') + '\nA: maybe, unsure how should I know.');
            }
            catch {
                await interaction.followUp('An error occurred while attempting to send the reply, please try again')
                    .catch(logging.error(`Log:A error occurred while trying to send error message `))
                    .then(logging.error( 'A error occurred while sending response 2, returning'))
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (randomnumber === 3) {
            log.info(`Log:A response 3 was selected, printing response 3`);

            try {
                await interaction.reply('Q: ' + interaction.options.getString('question') + '\nA: definitely not, I am not sure why you would even ask');
            }
            catch {
                await interaction.followUp('An error occurred while attempting to send the reply, please try again')
                    .catch(logging.error(`Log:A error occurred while trying to send error message `))
                    .then(logging.error( 'A error occurred while sending response 3, returning'))
                return;
            }
        }
    },
}
```

The other part is a function that prints responses if production mode is off:

```
const logging = {
    info: function(msg) {
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            return 0;
        }
        else {      
            log.info(msg);
        }
        return 0;
    },

    error: function(msg) {
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            log.error(msg);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm using
nodeJS v16.17.0
discord.js v14
and Winston for logging

Edit:

I apologize for being very vague and for the large volume of code, the expected output of this function is supposed to do the following

- loads the question from the getString() function
- logs to a file (debug.log) that the command /8ball was called
- generates a random number
- replies with a response that changes based of the value of `randomnumber`
- logs if an error occurred with replying to the user
- logs that ccb replied successfully
- returns

but what the files do is this (in worse cases)

- logs that 8ball has been called
- sends `deferReply()`
- halts, does not write anything to debug.log, no error message, no success message, nothing, and stays on "CCB is thinking"

also: I am aware that there is no handler for `randomnumber` being 0, the reason for that is when I first created /8ball, the `randomnumber` variable never seemed to respond with 0 so I emitted it for performance

also keep in mind that each time production mode has not been on

thanks again in advance

Comment: Your question has a lot of code, which makes it hard to answer. Can you provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: i hate to say it but all of my code is interlinked and I'm pushing it the way it is, there's a lot I have

Comment: @AlexHerbert Often just the act of isolating the code that causes the error is enough to lead you to the solution, and if not, then it will lead the community to a solution much faster.

Comment: Im not sure what the issue is that you are wanting to fix, I se ethat you dont have an if statement for the possibility of the random number being 0, maybe thats it, but beyond that, what is the specific issue it faces? And are the logs within the conditionals working as well, or is it all together not getting past the conditionals

Comment: Is your problem `let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);`? I mean the rest of the code try/catch and log messages some kind of repeats several times. Can it be that there are cases where randomnumber is not 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: @PsiKai thank you, I'm still new to stack overflow, and knowing that now helps, until now i thought I had to create a snippet that you could paste in a js file and run it and it will produce the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```js
let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
```

Why not use an array?

```js
let randomNumber = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
let randomPercent = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumber.length);
let getRandomNumber = randomNumber[randomPercent];
```

Look at the snippet to know if this is you need.

```js
let randomNumber = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
let randomPercent = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumber.length);
let getRandomNumber = randomNumber[randomPercent];
console.log(getRandomNumber);
```

EDIT:

You're using `if (randomnumber === 1)` which is when you get a random number then the bot will response a random log. What'd you expect?

Comment: the edit is very vague to me, what do you mean by a random log? also are you saying that  "which is when you get a random number" do you mean that when  I use `if(randomnumber === 1)` that it will return `true` because the number does or does not exist or something like that? because I'm confused. i do appreciate it but this not what I need, randomnum does not appear to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use if else if else so many times! Use variables instead!

Try this code in the 'execute:'

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    logging.info(`Log:8ball command was called printing a random message`);
    let responses = ['yes, i suppose', 'maybe, unsure how should I know.', 'definitely not, I am not sure why you would even ask']; // All responses are here
    let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length); // Outputs an array between 0 and responses.length -1
    let randomresponse = responses[randomnumber]; // Get the random response

    if (interaction.options.getString('question').includes('?') === true) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Sorry, but this command does not support question marks', ephemeral: true })
            .catch(logging.error(`Log:A error occurred while trying to send error message in 8ball`))

        return;
    }

    log.info(`Log:A response ${randomnumber} was selected, printing response ${randomnumber}`);
    try {
        await interaction.reply('Q: ' + interaction.options.getString('question') + `\nA: ${randomresponse}`);

    }
    catch {
        await interaction.followUp('An error occurred while attempting to send the reply, please try again')
            .catch(logging.error(`Log:A error occurred while trying to send error message `))
            .then(logging.error(`A error occurred while sending response ${randomnumber}, returning`))
        return;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ^-^

[+] : You can add infinite responses in the responses Array!

Answer (score 0):

i appreciate all of your time even when now the fix seems so obvious

@Tachanks and @Kodeur_Kubic were correct,

I found the fix was to use arrays as @Kodeur_Kubic answered, and as @Tachanks suggested I forgot the handler for 0

so for others future reference here's the resulting code that was fixed

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { logging } = require('../index')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('8ball')
        .setDescription('Ask me a question')
        .addStringOption(opt => 
            opt.setName('question')
            .setDescription('question you have for meh')
            .setRequired(true)),
    
    async execute(interaction) {

        //defines the invoker
        const invokerRaw = interaction.user.tag;

        //defines the invoker as a string
        const invoker = invokerRaw.toString();

        //defines the question as questionRaw
        const question = interaction.options.getString('question');

        //creates a array for responces
        const responce = ['yes, i suppose', 'maybe, idk how should i know?', 'defininately not, im not sure why you would even ask', 'ask me later, im busy!'];
        
        //logs to debug.log that the 8ball commands was called and to genorate a random message
        logging.info(`8ball command was called printing a random message`);

        //random number object
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

        //try to see if the question has a ? in it
        if(question.includes('?') === true) {

            //prints to the user that the question contained a question mark
            await interaction.reply({ content:'Sorry, but this command does not support question marks', ephemeral:true })
                .catch((err) => {

                    //logs the error to debug.log
                    logging.error(err);
                })
                .then(() => {

                    //logs to debug.log that we sent the error message
                    logging.info('Error message sent to ' + invoker);
                })

            //returns
            return 1;
        }

        await interaction.reply(`Q: ${question}\nA: ${responce[randomNumber]}`)
            .catch((err) => {

                //logs the error to debug.log
                logging.error(err.name);
            })
            .then(() => {

                //logs to debug.log that we sent the reply
                logging.info('sent reply successfully')
            })
    },
}
```

Comment: For the random number DONT USE A NUMBER!! Use responce.length instead!